# umbraco: How to get the value _umb_password property

Tags: angularjs, umbraco

I have a Groups tab(its a properties tab of a member) where i have property **_umb_password** under it i have to controls alias **password** and **confirmpassword**.
[image]

I am trying to enter the value to alias "password" and "confirmpassword" using angular js on form load.
any idea how to get the value property of **password** and **confirmpassword**

Comment: Do you have any sample code or more context? e.g. is the Angular script a custom property editor? Are you attempting to access a field outside of the context of the angular $scope, are the properties defined in the angular template, can they be bound to the controller scope?

Comment: No, i dont defined them as they are system properties i think, i am creating a function where i am trying to get the system properties. I am able to get the _umb_password property but not the required one.

Comment: The Groups tab nothing but the Properties tab of a member.